# How to fetch multiple API Request or URL at the same time?

Tags: javascript

I want to fetch multiple URLs or API request at the same time and i think sending multiple fetch
requests simultaneously is not  the right solution. Is there any way so i can retrieve JSON data from
two or more than two URL ?

```
function fetchData(){
  let url1 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData';  
  let url2 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offlineUserData';
  fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
             console.log(data);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function fetchData(){
  let urls = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offlineUserData'
  ]
  let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url));
  Promise.all(requests)
  .then(responses => responses.forEach(
    response => console.log(`${response.url}: ${response.status}`)
  ));
}
```

You can use `Promise.all`

https://javascript.info/promise-api

Comment: and how to retrive those data from url ? like i have these type of data in url users: [["Month", "Anam", "Panam", "duliyan"], ["Apr-16", 21, 26, 29], ["May-07", 0, 0, 5]]

Comment: @SauravShrestha I think it could be another problem. You should make another question about it with your codes and results.

Comment: Okay 
then i have to delete this post then

Comment: @SauravShrestha I don't understand your stance. Why do you have to delete it? If you have another question, you have to post one again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64641102/how-to-fetch-multiple-api-request-or-url-and-retrieve-data-from-each-url-or-api
This is link of another question.I hope you understand my question