# How to fetch multiple API Request or URL and retrieve data from each URL or API Request?

Tags: javascript

In this method, I have fetched a single API Request URL

```
function fetchData() {
  let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData';
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      var users=data.users;
      console.log(data.users);
    });
}
```

and when I do `console.log(data.users)`. Result or data will come like this.

```
[["Month", "Anam", "Panam", "duliyan"], ["Apr-16", 21, 26, 29], ["May-07", 0, 0, 5]]
```

But now I want to fetch multiple URLs or API request and retrieve each API Request data at the same time.
From this link I found the uses of promise but I don't how to use retrieve individual API Request Data
[How to fetch multiple API Request or URL at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639891/how-to-fetch-multiple-API-request-or-URL-at-the-same-time/64639922#64639922)

```
function fetchData() {
  let urls = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offlineUserData'
  ]
  let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url));
  Promise.all(requests)
    .then(responses => responses.forEach(
      response => console.log(`${response.url}: ${response.status}`)
    ));
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you did with the answer. show your edited code.

Comment: @jinongun I just want to fetch two API  URL and retrieve data from those URL 
and put in variable like var online-user and var offline-user.The main point of this i want to sum/add those data from two URL.

Comment: have you tried to see the `console.log`? what did you see?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userOnlineData    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userOfflineData  200  This in console.log() from your solution

Comment: Why don't you check `response`? I am not giving you the answer. I am just giving you advice. You should think about that. try `console.log(response)` instead of `console.log(response.url);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code to the following:

```
function fetchData(){
    let urls = [
     {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData',
        type: 'offline'
     },
     {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offlineUserData',
        type: 'offline'
     },
     {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData',
        type: 'online'
     },
    ];


    let requests = urls.map(item => fetch(item.url).then(response => response.json()));

    const resultData = { offline: [], online: [] };

    Promise.all(requests)
     .then(datas => {
       datas.forEach(
        (data, i) => {
         const url = urls[i];
         if (url.type === 'offline') 
             resultData.offine.push({...url, data});
         if (url.type === 'online') 
             resultData.online.push({...url, data});
        });

        console.log({resultData});
        /*
          {
             resultData: {
                offline: [
                  {
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/oflineUserData',
                    type: 'offline',
                    data: [...]
                  },
                  {
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offlineUserData',
                    type: 'offline',
                    data: [...]
                  },
                ],
                online: [
                  {
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData',
                    type: 'online',
                    data: [...]
                  },
                ]
             }
           }
        */
       }
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response 
but Suppose there two variable like online and offline and i want store each API Request data in variable respectively.like    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData' data coming from this URL in online variable and http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offlineUserData in offline variable .

Comment: Can you update your answer with the snippet of how you want the result to be in the end

Comment: Let say i have two different URL 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData',
     'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offlineUserData'
I just only need to fetch them and retrive their data

Comment: In my question,I have fetched my single URL let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onlineUserData';
  fetch(url){}

Comment: I have updated the answer check the log about the output, see if it helps

Comment: So What can i do if i have to retrieve data of offline only ? console.log({resultData.offline }) does this work ?

Comment: yes it will work, make sure you define `type: offline` within `urls`

Comment: Can i ask you different question ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64658732/how-to-sum-if-name-and-date-match-two-api-json-data
here is my question